# Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in /public_html/website/index.php on line

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to get data from database. I got this error bellow. problem is that this code bellow is used on my other project and it's working great. Does someone knows where is the problem ?

I got this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in /public_html/website/index.php on line
```

CODE:

```
include 'scripts/db_conn.php';
include 'scripts/functions.php';

$prep_stmt = "SELECT date FROM blocked_dates WHERE date >= CURDATE();";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);
    $stmt->execute();
    if (!$stmt) {
        die('There was an error running the query [' . $mysqli->error . ']');
        exit();
    }
    $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();
    while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) {
        $parameters[] = & $row[$field->name];
    }

    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $parameters);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
            $x[$key] = $val;
        }
        $results[] = $x;
    }
```

Comment: "mysqli_prepare() returns a statement object or FALSE if an error occurred." Seems pretty clear the prepare is failing and returning false. Add a check for this before you call execute on what you think is a valid statement object.

Answer (score 0):

You cant bind on object to a new variable.

Try to start your code like this:

```
$stmt = new Mysqli();
```

After connecting to database,

```
$stmt->prepare($prep_stmt);
$debug = $stmt->execute();

if (!$debug) {
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $mysqli->error . ']');
    exit();
}

$meta = $stmt->result_metadata();

while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) {
    $parameters[] = & $row[$field->name];
}

call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $parameters);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
        $x[$key] = $val;
    }
    $results[] = $x;
}
```